# I need a SQL which gets all clients which date of birth includes in range

Tags: sql, mysql

I need a SQL which gets all clients which date of birth includes in range.

The date in db looks like dd.mm.yyyy

I need a sql request which gets all users by range in example

```
SELECT * from `users` WHERE `date` BEETWEEN '25.01' AND '25.04'
```

Then get all users which have a birthday in this range

I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_clients` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '{$event_start}' AND '{$event_end}'
```

but it dependes from year

Comment: _"The date in db looks like dd.mm.yyyy"_ - stored as a _text_ data type? If so, that is the very first thing you should change. Use a proper DATE column type for this.

Comment: I changed it already now its date

Comment: You'll likely need to pull out the Month and Day from the date and compare each part, so you can ignore the year. The mysql MONTH() and DAY() can help on the SQL side. From PHP you can use the DateTime class to do something similar.

Comment: So guys I found how to do it without refactoring database

Comment: Good. P.S. We didn't suggest refactoring the database (except changing the column type to DATE, which you said you'd already done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_clients` WHERE MONTH(`date`)*100+DAY(`date`) BETWEEN 125 AND 425
```

So, convert the date in the DB to a number using `month*100 + day` (irrespective of the year) and then check it to be in a date-range as numbers (also without year)

Here, both 0125 and 0425 are inclusive.